# Numbers from both lists being deleted?

Tags: python, list, loops

I do not understand why my 3 from y is being deleted in the following code. I assume it is some aliasing problem, but is there any way to let y retain the number when x has it removed?

```
  x = []
  y = []

  for i in range (10):
      if i == 5:
          y.append(x)
          del x[3]
       x.append(i)

print (x)
print (y)
```

Output:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Could you show us what you expect the output to be? I'm not clear on what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to append a copy of `x` to y:

```
y.append(x[:])
```

`y.append(x)` appends the list that is referenced by `x`, so `y` essentially is `[x]`. Because it is `x` that is contained by `y`, and not any other list, you are changing the value of `y` when you change `x`.

Also, if `x` is a nested list, you might want to consider taking a *deepcopy* of `x` like so:

```
import copy
y.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
```

So that each of the nested lists are copies, and not the same lists in `x`.

Comment: "so if you change x, you change the list in y" makes it sound as if there's two lists - which there are not, as you explain later